# About buffer overflow Win 10 x64

Tags: buffer-overflow

In my  job as a system administrator I developed a C program that can handle links like `intranet://` from the browser. The software can open ie or url like this `intranet ://ie`. The url is the same for Chrome but I see the code and is it vulnerable to buffer overflow because it has a limited buffer of 300.

Is it dangerous same with Windows protection and CPU protection (canary, cookie,... ) I don't have the skills to develop an exploit.

When I give a lot of `AAA...` to the software it generates an application error in Windows logs.

Comment: Security mitigations in some cases can be bypassed, don't count on those protection mechanisms. A buffer overflow is a critical vulnerability since in most cases it allows RCE. From the information you provided I don't know if your program can be successfully exploited but since you developed the program and you know the bug, I guess the best thing you can do is to use good coding practices and fix it so it's not vulnerable any more.